# Creating a Power Point presentation in Excel with default SlideMaster

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am building a macro that takes excel data and puts in PowerPoint presentation, however the presentation that is created from scratch by my macro contains default Office SlideMaster in opposition to a new presentation created by opening PowerPoint manually which contains SlideMaster loaded from
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\blank.potx which is a company slidemaster. I want the macro to create a presentation with company slidemaster, the problem is that the macro will be ran on different computers therefore I can not use the path to blank.potx (username changes).

Is it possible to make it work that way?

Here is the beggining of my code:

```
Sub mainsub()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim mySlide2 As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim myShape1 As Object
Dim myShape2 As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set formularz = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("formularz")

On Error Resume Next

Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

Err.Clear

If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

If Err.Number = 429 Then
MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)

With myPresentation.PageSetup
.SlideWidth = 800
.SlideHeight = 450
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("formularz").Activate

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate
PowerPointApp.WindowState = 2

mySlide.Select
Set myShape1 = mySlide.Shapes.addTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 100)

    text1 = formularz.Range("B2").text
    myShape1.TextFrame.TextRange.text = text1
    myShape1.top = 0
    myShape1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Helvetica 75"
    myShape1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 102, 0)
    myShape1.TextFrame.WordWrap = 0
    myShape1.left = 400 - myShape1.width / 2

PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
```

.
.
.

and so on, mainly creating great number of another slides and shapes. 
Probably the answer to my question is (to be put) somewhere in above code.

Thanks for any piece of advice

Comment: Im doing something like you, but with different aproach. I have stored presentation template in workbook and based on that, i creating worksheet to which i saving data which i needed. And because of template presentation stored in workbook there is no need for loading slideMaster or template from drive.

Comment: environ("appdata") will return the path to C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming for the current user XXX.  Add the rest of the path to the templates directory and you're good to go, assuming that the template you want has already been installed for every user.

Comment: @LubošSuk
Unfortuantely it happens that not every user has the .potx file in the above directory :( Lubos could you show us the code you are using to apply Excel Template into the presentation that is created?